# Syntax error in select statement in sql

Tags: sql

In comand:

```
SELECT * FROM "Messages" author = 'spikinas' )
```

I got:

```
near "=": syntax error:
```

How should i change comand line for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM "Messages" WHERE author = 'spikinas'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM "Name Of Your Table Without the Quotes"
WHERE author = 'spikinas'
```

Make sure 'spikinas' starts with LOWER CASE s, if not change the sql to 'Spikinas' UPPER CASE S

Comment: what on earth has the case of the literal go to do with it?  You have absolutely no idea what collation the OP is using